# Create CSS classes from Google Sheet Column Data

Tags: css, google-sheets

I have an HTML/SVG trade show map, where I'd like to auto-update the color of certain divs (booths), based on whether they're booked/available.

I have a google sheets file, where I'd like to pull certain data, and create/update CSS classes, to reflect which booths are sold and which ones are open.

I've attached a few screenshots.

1. Floorplan map, showing the booths. Currently, I manually update the booth's CSS when it's "sold" (blue), from the default green.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/I86vv.jpg
2. Google Sheet sample. I'm looking for the booth color to change to "sold" (blue), when the input in column D (STATUS) in the Google Sheet for that booth reads "paid"... and to automatically update, when I edit/save the Google Sheet.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyxHp.jpg

Here's a sample of the SVG code for one of the booth's in the map.

```
<polygon boothname="B3" class="fill" occ="" points="192,166 243,166 243,205 231,233 192,233 " x="217.5" y="199.5" myicon="0" width="0" height="0" fill="#0f4983" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" locked="0" isinvisible="0" fill-opacity="1"/>
<foreignObject style="pointer-events: none;" id="253text" x="192.5" y="184.5" width="50" height="30">
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="253textdiv" align="center" class="boothTextNoSelect" style=" display: table; font-family: Arial; width:100%; height:100%; padding: 5px; font-size:10px; line-height:1;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:9px" id="253textdiv2">B3</div>
  </div>
</foreignObject>
<!--- End of BOOTH B3-->
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hey there - can you provide a sample sheet and eventually explain *what exactly* are you trying to achieve? Also, can you post what have you tried as well?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search / research efforts as is suggested in [ask]